# Cant make relationship between two node properties in NEO4J dynamically

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am trying to build relationship in between 2 properties in  graphdb. I have a csv file like this

```
RELATIONSHIP,AGENTID,CUSTOMERID,TXNID,TIMESTAMP,AMOUNT,CHANNEL
hasrelation,17956,2025,6C13MXSESN,2019-03-01T11:52:08,1000,USSD
hasrelation,17957,2026,6C13MXSEVF,2019-03-01T11:52:09,5000,BAPP
```

In my Neo4j GUI I have created two node AGENT and CUSTOMER separately
For AGENT

```
ID,SHOPNAME,DIVISION,DISTRICT,THANA

17956,CONNECT DISTRIBUTION,DHAKA,GAZIPUR,Gazipur Sadar
17957,HUMAYUN KABIR,DHAKA,DHAKA,Demra
```

for Customer node

```
ID,DIVISION,DISTRICT,THANA,REGDATE,APPREGDATE
2025,KHULNA,JESSORE,JESSORE SADAR,2019-02-14,
2026,DHAKA,TANGAIL,KALIHATI,2017-02-10
```

last column is empty in this case

So I have written the query by reference of Neo4J community

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///test.csv" AS row
MATCH (f:Agent), (s:Customer)
WHERE f.ID = row.AGENTID
AND s.ID = row.CUSTOMERID
CALL apoc.create.relationship(f, row.RELATIONSHIP,{}, s) YIELD rel
return rel
```

but no relationship is created between them .Since I am very new to neo4j kindly suggest me which thing I am missing here and help me to solve this  thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks right, so I would try confirming that your match statements are behaving as you expect.

Depending on how you've created your test nodes, these conditional checks:

```
WHERE f.ID = row.AGENTID
AND s.ID = row.CUSTOMERID
```

might be the problem. The load_csv function treats everything it loads as strings initially, but you might have created the nodes with integer-based IDs.

Try:

```
WHERE f.ID = toInteger(row.AGENTID)
AND s.ID = to.Integer(row.CUSTOMERID)
```

If that doesn't work, you could try replacing your MATCH statements with MERGE, which would help confirm the source of the problem (don't forget to clean up duplicate nodes if you go this route).